Why does Image.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) fail to sum the multi-band values correctly?
I found the sums of multi-band values calculated by .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) and .expression() were inconsistent in the following code.
You can see from the figure below that for the pixel value of an example pixel (the red point), one result is 610 and the other result is 707.
It can be seen that the result of .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) is incorrect. Why?
import ee
import geemap


ee.Initialize()


soil_bulk_density = ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/bdod_mean")

reducer_sum = soil_bulk_density.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())

def sum_by_expression (image):
    return image.expression(
        'b(0) + b(1) + b(2) + b(3) + b(4) + b(5)'
    )

expression_sum = sum_by_expression(soil_bulk_density)


Map = geemap.Map()
Map
Map.addLayer(soil_bulk_density, {}, 'original data')
Map.addLayer(reducer_sum, {}, 'reducer')
Map.addLayer(expression_sum, {}, 'expression')
Map.addLayer(ee.Geometry.Point([59.233, 67.989]), {'color': 'red'}, 'point')


---Additional information---
According to @Es_a's comments, I test it in the JS code. I find the inconsistent values only exist in the coarse-scale pixels which contain masked pixels and this inconsistency will disappear when I zoom in.
So does this mean that I will get inconsistent results if I export them at coarse scales? And I don't understand how .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) can calculate such a value at this condition (see the following figure).


However, in the Python code, this inconsistency always exists no matter the map's scale. You can see even in a very fine scale, the two values are still inconsistent (same as the values in the coarse scale but both of them should be 'masked' in expectation). I think maybe it is due to how geemap.Map() works but I can't understand it.


What does the image show? Do you mean inconsistency in the pixel values or inconsistency in the way the two layers look on the map stacked on top of each others! The pixel values look consistent in the JS replica of your code https://code.earthengine.google.com/761b50744e782c448bc8f3adb7c4a7eb. The latter (how they look on the map) this is related to the way earth engine handle pyramid and tiles to show the result on the fly for a given zoom level, it shouldn't be an issue for calculations and it should disappear when you export or zoom in (GEE would recalculate for the new zoomed scale)

@Es_a. Thanks for your comments. I mean the inconsistency in the pixel values (as you can see one result is 610 and the other is 707). I have added more information and questions to the main text. In short, According to the JS code, I find the inconsistent values only exist in the coarse-scale pixels which contain masked pixels and this inconsistency will disappear when I zoom in.  But in the Python code, this inconsistency always exists no matter the map's scale, and I think maybe it is due to how geemap.Map() works but I can't understand it.

I find the edit and info to be controversial. There is no inconsistent pixel values in the JS version no matter the scale (how they appear on the map is a different thing). And NO that would not affect your calculations or export. Finally, the JS code shows the same coordinate in the screenshot with consistent values; while yours shows % next to bands, indicating there is a resampling behind the calculation. This is a result of either clicking in a coarse resolution while the map is still on the fly processing (click again to show without %) or you used different code that resample it

Reducers weight the pixels according to the image mask; addition doesn't.
You can see in the inspection that the input pixels and the final pixel have a mask of approximately 81%. 724*0.81 = 586.  If you don't want weighted reduction (the default), use an unweighted reducer.

I get it. Thanks for your answer. I find this page (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_weighting) based on your answer. It provide a further explanation.
